# Find number of available processors in maven (platform-independent)

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

Is it possible to retrieve the number of available processors in maven in a platform-independent way? I'd like to be able to activate a profile if `available_processors > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that. You'd have to write a Maven extension that stores the result of `Runtime.availableProcessors()` in a System Property. You'd have to put that extension in `$Maven_HOME/lib/ext` (see [MNG-4984](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4984)). Writing a Maven Plugin is not enough, Plugin resolution happens after profile activation. I don't think it would be possible to write a custom [`ProfileActivator`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/apidocs/org/apache/maven/profiles/activation/ProfileActivator.html), mainly because the pom.xml XSD won't allow it.